# Screen session fails when detaching

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have successfully used the `screen` utility to run my time consuming scripts when I am working on a server via `ssh`. However lately I have been running into a problem, I have found my script terminated mid-process with the following message on the `screen` log

```
 : cannot connect to X server localhost:10.0
```

What could be the issue here? If it makes any difference I was connecting from OSX with XQuartz running, and ssh -Y to connect to a remote server running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Why are you using the `-Y` option to `ssh`?  Are you using the ssh connection to do anything other than run scripts within a remote `screen` session?  If your script needs to launch `X11` clients, you probably don't want to execute it within a (potentially) detached `screen` session.

Comment: @user4556274 It's out of habit actually; the script generates pdf plots and saves them. While I was developing the script, I wanted to manually investigate the plots generated, thus having X-forwarding. As it is, the script should not launch any X11 clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-Y` is your issue.  The script you're running is trying to connect to a display and is, for whatever reason, connecting to the one forwarded over your `ssh` session instead of the local one.  When the `ssh` session dies (ie. you disconnect) the display goes away and the script fails.  Remove the `-Y` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Likely, but I am fairly certain that did not cause problems before. I am under the impression that the crux of the issue might be that if I am not using my mac the energy saving settings might be terminating the connection and thus killing the screen session.

Comment: Even if it is sleep settings the fact that you have multiple displays available to the script over-complicates things.  Try it without the `-Y` and see what happens.

Comment: Will do, will return to this when I've tested this out